How do linear wings reconcile with volatility frowns
I was recently looking at a paper that brought up that under certain market conditions the risk neutral density can exhibit thin tails, yielding a volatility frown as opposed to the more usual volatility smile. However, I am also aware of the constraint that in the limit of log strike, implied volatility must be linear. If a volatility smirk is sloping downwards in the wings, and we require asymptotic linearity, then obviously the smirk cannot extend forever, as at some point the I.V would turn negative, which makes no sense.
My question is regarding what the allowable shape in the wings can be for a volatility frown. Do the wings have to have asymptotically 0 gradient, or can it begin, at some point, to turn upwards and then show a total volatility smile that has more than one local minima?
I also would like to ask if anyone has any datasets that have exhibited volatility frowns. I would like to investigate elements of the frown myself, but unfortunately I don't have any data that exhibits that behavior. It would be helpful if, in addition to the first question, I could be pointed to a resource where I could confirm that behavior and play around with it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

It's always useful to add a paper. Without details I'd say it's something like Amazon around earnings.
